# How to rename an Outlook 365 Exchange mailbox after a domain change?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, office365

When we registered for Office 365 we were assigned a default domain ending with *.onmicrosoft.com* and some users were created with that domain, receiving corresponding Exchange mailboxes. After migration to our own domain name these users still saw their mailboxes in Outlook with the default domain name with no option to change it (the input field in the account settings was disabled). There are several suggestions on the net to fix from editing to registry to invoking some obscure PowerShell scripts but none helped. Outlook always managed to get the old name from some place I couldn't identify. There was also no place in the Office 365 administration frontent where this could be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a (radical) solution myself: I finally managed to get Outlook to display the correct account name by deleting the following data - exit Outlook first!

- The complete folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`
- The complete registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\` (with all children)

Then, after starting Outlook again I had to create a new profile and the mailbox name was displayed correctly.

Please be aware that this approach may delete any data that is not (yet) stored online. **Use at your own risk!** And store a backup before if necessary.